# How does Avast check the router password strength?

Tags: router, passwords, anti-virus, avast

I just scanned my computer with Avast and it also did a check of my home network security. Now it's showing me, that my router password is too weak:
https://help.avast.com/en/ws_android/1/alert_weak_router_password.html

I'm using a TP-Link TD-W8970B with the newest firmware. The password is set to the maximum length of 15 characters and includes uppercase and lowercase letters and numbers. Special characters aren't allowed. So there's no way I could improve the security even if I wanted to. But how does Avast even determine that my password is too weak? It's saved in Firefox with a master password and in KeePass with a master password, so there's no way for Avast to know it.

Comment: Avast, by default, installs an extention for Firefox that allows it to see your Firefox passwords including the master password. You can disable this feature/extension (can't remember how but I'm sure you'll find the setting somewhere in the Avast application).

Comment: I don't have any Avast extension installed in Firefox. I didn't install the "Browser Security" extension. And I really doubt an extension could read my master password, that would make take away any point in using a master password at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late to the party on this one, but somebody else with a TP-Link router had the same warning that their password was too weak. Avast does check the router's admin interface username and password. I copied the info below from the Avast forums, in case it's of use to anyone else happening across this thread:

> I suddenly found I was getting the same weak password alert. I've been
>   busy making changes to my network  last few weeks so *had* had the
>   default admin password on the router, but even then I hadn't had this
>   warning previously on this machine the last full scan I'd done on it.
>   Only got the warning today so reset the routers admin interface
>   password, made no difference, rebooted router & machine numerous times
>   & it was still flagging it even though I'd definitely changed the
>   password.
>
> It's maybe just coincidence & was some later 'refreshing' of the data
>   avast was accessing (I'd already tried deleting the scan logs, btw, to
>   no success) but I finally got it passing after I'd looked into all my
>   router settings & **found there was a page with password access if you
>   used USB mass storage attached to the router. It, regardless of me
>   changing the main admin log-in still showed the old default one as
>   'master' but once I changed it, then rebooted the router, it passed
>   the Avast scan.**
>
> My particular router is a TP-Link one, but thought it worth sharing
>   the info just in case it's a solution for anyone else as during my
>   research earlier had noticed users with differing makes having the
>   same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two things, here.

Avast was checking your WIFI password, not the password to your router admin interface.

I am unsure how it works, but I guess it performs a dictionary attack on your wifi ... that is what the mobile version does. Weird, it forgets it already checked the wifi and does so again after a few days ...

This is avast on Android as provided with the phone manufacturer, btw.

BTW, TP-Link are a little light on security, multiple vulns reported in 2017 alone, not sure if you still have it and have updated the firmware since, here is a [list](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-11936/Tp-link.html) of CVE's.